# Just learned the hard way a piece of MySQL sytax - why does this work and what does it mean to do?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm using MySQL 5.6.  The internal app at my company works with `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`(I know).  I've brought this up before but was told to just let it be.

Today, I accidentally wrote and ran this
`DELETE FROM table WHERE id - 11235`, with a `-` instead of `=` and lo and behold all the rows deleted.  I understand delete all rows is allowable with the safe updates off, but why didn't this throw some syntax error?  What would `id - 11235` even mean in SQL?

Comment: it would try take 11235 from the value in id if it didnt result in an non valid number (eg an integer overrun Id guess) then it said yes I can delete that.

Comment: I ALWAYS run SELECT with the same condition before running  the DELETE on production environment. Just replace DELETE with SELECT * to test it.

Comment: @PeterHe Yea I normally do too.  I've been brutally reminded why that is a good practice.

Comment: @PeterHe:  a step further,  `SELECT t.* FROM mytable t WHERE ... ` to test, then   `CREATE TABLE save_rows_from_mytable  AS SELECT t.* FROM mytable t ... ` to preserve the rows to be deleted (if there are any SET NULL or CASCADE foreign keys referencing the table, write statements to save the referencing rows that will be affected, `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT c.* FROM mytable t JOIN childtable c ON ... WHERE ... `,  and again if those tables are referenced by foreign keys. Then to do the delete, the original `SELECT t.*` statement, replace `SELECT` with `DELETE`.

Comment: That's a nasty little "gotcha" - +1 for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works in MySQL because MySQL is non-standard with respect to SQL boolean expressions.

Boolean expressions must evaluate to `true` or `false`. But in MySQL, `false` is simply the integer 0, `true` is the integer 1, and any other integer other than 0 is also treated as true.

So it is strange, and non compliant with ANSI SQL, but any arithmetic expression can also be used as a boolean expression, and vice-versa.

This allows us to do neat tricks like this:

```
SELECT SUM( name = 'Harry' ) FROM mytable
```

The boolean expression results in integer values, either 0 or 1, depending on the string comparison. Summing these effectively returns a count of the rows where the expression is true, the same as if we had run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Harry'
```

But the SUM trick allows us to "count" multiple conditions with a single pass over the table:

```
SELECT SUM(name = 'Harry'), SUM(name = 'Ron'), SUM(name = 'Hermione') FROM mytable
```

You can't do that with COUNT(*) and a WHERE clause.

Again, this works only in MySQL, because MySQL makes booleans and integers the same. It doesn't work in other implementations of SQL.

In your query, `id - 11235` is 0 on a row where id = 11235, and it's nonzero on every other row. The rows where it is nonzero are treated as true, so the delete is applied.

This is unfortunate at least in your case, because a typo results in deleting all your data.

Comment: `So it is strange, and non compliant with ANSI SQL` - MySQL isn't compliant with ANSI SQL? **NO**, shurely shome mishtake? Quite frankly, I'm shocked, flummoxed, bamboozled and perplexed!

Comment: @Vérace, can you name another popular SQL implementation that is compliant with ANSI SQL?

Comment: No, but I also definitely can't name a mainstream SQL product that plays so fast and so loose with the standard! Despite improvement in recent times (`CHECK` constraints 30 years after everybody else had them!), it's still chock-full of "gotchas"!

Answer (score 5):

You have a `DELETE`-statement with a condition (`WHERE`). If the condition is true for the row, the delete operation is being done.

The condition you have is `id - 11235`. Every row where this condition doesn’t produce `false`/`0` is considered `true`. So, the command will delete all the rows but id 11235 (11235-11235 = 0).

Comment: It means TRUE or 0. In MySQL zero is same as false. 11234-11235 is -1, which is considered TRUE. 11235-11235 is 0, which is considered FALSE.